# Restrict option loading (react-select) on entering the first three characters for faster response time

Tags: reactjs, drop-down-menu, react-select

Here I am trying to load the options only after user inputs first 3 characters, such that the problem of loading the huge list of options every time a character is entered can be controlled.

```
render(){
let options = arrayName.map(name => {
      return { value: name.name, label: name.name };
    })

return(
<Select
                openMenuOnFocus={false}
                openMenuOnClick={false}
                options={options}
                value={this.state.inputValue}
                onChange={this.handleChange}
                placeholder="Please Enter 3 Characters..."
              />
     )
}
```

So far I used "openMenuOnFocus={false} and openMenuOnClick={false}" which works well by not showing the drop down list at first, but I want to let user input 3 characters and then only load the drop down with the huge list fetched from the API.

Otherwise it makes the performance of my application slow.

Kindly suggest some best possible ways to mitigate the response time issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the best solution is to debounce api call, not to send it only when the user texts at least 3 characters :)

First of all, use the [async version](https://react-select.com/async) of react-select and then [lodash debounce](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#debounce)

With `debounce` the api call will be executed only if the elapsed time between 
 keydown events is greater than the second argoment of the `debounce` function.

Hope it can be helpful :)

Comment: Thank you, I tried the lodash debounce method, but I am not sure if I am doing it right, please have a look once: below added code

Comment: ```
In constructor:
 this.namesDataLoad = debounce(this.namesDataLoad, 3000);


  handleChange = value => {
      this.setState({...this.state, inputValue: value});
      if(value.length > 3){
        this.namesDataLoad();
      }
    }

    namesDataLoad() {
      let {arrayName} = this.state;
      narrowedData.map(name => {
        arrayName.push({ name: name.name });
      })
      this.setState({arrayName})
    }
 
and render stays the same:
render(){
let options = arrayName.map(name => {
      return { value: name.name, label: name.name };
    })
```